# Disable Liferay Cookies programmatically

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

is there a way to disable liferay cookies programmatically not using properties in portal-ext ?!
I mean using on/off button on privacy page to enable user using cookies or not

Answer (score 2):

An answer on stackoverflow needs to have 30 characters, but this question would require only 2:

No

What's the problem you're trying to solve? AFAIK Liferay generates only session cookies unless you specifically check the "Remember me" option at login. And that option can be disabled in configuration - I'd not do it programmatically.

Comment: Hi @Olaf,

I want to prevent cookie download on browser in Liferay which are non essential for user like Google Analytics Cookies. Is there any way we can filter Cookie creation?
I've one requirement that, Non Essential cookies not download on client browser.

Comment: GA cookies don't come from Liferay, but from google. Just don't use GA if you don't want their cookies.

Comment: I accepted what you say.
I've requirement that :
if user click on Accept button(button available on theme level) then GA cookies will downloaded on Browser  otherwise not.

That thing I need to handle by LR 6.2.
So, WRT is there any approach which I can follow?